# react use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render json with html tags

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, eslint

I am trying to render a json list with html tags in the string in a list as follows [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/deqiqeb/edit?js,console,output). It works in Jsbin. But in my console I got warning below:

```
warning  Only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` react/no-danger-with-children
```

just wonder if there is other way to render the list with dangerouslySetInnerHTML to avoid the warning?

```
const displayList = [
    {
        item: 1,
        text: "<strong>ABC</strong> this should be strong."
    },
    {
        item: 2,
        text: "<a>ABC</a> this should be link."
    },
    {
        item: 3,
        text: "normal text"
    }
];

const App = () => (
    <ul>
        {displayList.map((item, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: item.text
                }}>
                </div>
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React is complaining about the use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in conjunction with safe react children, that happened when you let the div tag opened to such characteristic `<div>open and ready for children</div>`.

Since you are using the JSX syntax extension, the solution here is write the whole sentence in a single line:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.text}}></div>
```

or just using a singleton div tag:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
       __html: item.text
     }}/>
```

By the way you are not getting the error on jsbin because it is a react production build, this build is not meant to tell you what could be written better.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the enclosing tag of your `div` element in your component so that it looks like the following code:

```js
<li key={i}>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: item.text
     }} />
</li>
```

According to [this](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-danger-with-children.md), it should remove the warning.

Comment: This.. I have been looking for this everywhere.. Thank you