# How can I pass a string to a react component and have it treated as html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react component where one of the properties passed is a string.
However this string is an html component, such as,

```
            <Example time="4 <sup> th </sup>  September">
                Text
            </Example>
```

However on my received component I want this to be rendered as html instead of a string.

`<h6 className="..."> {time} </h6>`

Comment: Could you provide more context to this? What is the property look like?

Comment: I think I might have an answer for this, but need to make sure it matches your needs.

Comment: Can you try to provide us a bit more context for what you are trying to accomplish. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Are you just wanting to render the `time` prop into a header element?

Comment: @RyanLe I thought I did, the example provided above it like what I am trying to achieve. I have a react component which takes a date, as a string, however I want to utilize the <sup> tag in my date. So I am trying to figure out how I can pass a string and render it essentially as an html tag.

Comment: Does your `<sup>` come from some property? Try to provide more context to your question.. Like where are your properties came from, and how the whole component looks like.

Comment: <sup> is not something I made it is a html tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render json with html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795680/react-use-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-to-render-json-with-html-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML
```

from docs

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

here is docs [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly you want to show html given from another source (usually as text)
`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is under the DOM elements in react as an attribute and is React's replacement for `innerHTML` known from vanilla JavaScript

when using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute you need to send an object with an `__html` key like so:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 'beware of dangerously Set InnerHTML' }}>
```

watch out of this attribute, its not called this way for no reason, unvigilent usage can open you up for cross-site scripting attack ([XSS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting))

further explanation thanks to @FrancisJohn in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337289/react-js-set-innerhtml-vs-dangerouslysetinnerhtml) thread:

> the scenes when you use dangerouslySetInnerHTML it lets React know
> that the HTML inside of that component is not something it cares
> about.
>
> Because React uses a virtual DOM, when it goes to compare the diff
> against the actual DOM, it can straight up bypass checking the
> children of that node because it knows the HTML is coming from another
> source. So there's performance gains.